# Java Mail Api throws MessagingException: Exception reading response

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send a mail using localhost and Java Mail Api, however when sending the mail an exception is generated

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2202)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.close(SMTPTransport.java:1212)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:257)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.monoplus.mcd.JavaMailApi.sendMail(JavaMailApi.java:87)
    at com.monoplus.mcd.SendMailMain.main(SendMailMain.java:18)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:124)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:89)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2182)
    ... 13 more
```

My Postfix is running and its configuration is the default.

Also, port 25 is in listening status

And I'm able to connect using `telnet localhost 25`

Source code is at https://bitbucket.org/saavedrah_/javamail/src/master/

Thank you

Comment: What do you use as SMTP server?

Comment: The external server does not seem to be responding in time(SocketTimeoutException),  you could increase the time out, but I would first check that the external server responds for the address using an alternative(email box) if possible.

Answer (score 0):

In my build.gradle I had a reference to these two libraries

```
    implementation 'javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.6.2'
    implementation 'javax.mail:mail:1.5.0-b01'
```

when removing the javax.mail-api reference the mail was sent without any problem.

Thank you